# How can I create a tabset in this flexdashboard layout

Tags: r-markdown, flexdashboard

Pretty sure i'm missing something obvious here but..

[image]

How would I reconfigure the code so that  chart 3 is a tabset?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

In order to provide an answer (an unsatisfactory one, tough), it is to point out that this is a known issue, and currently does not have a solution in `flexdashboard`.

Source in Github: https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/37

Answer (score 1):

As I dont have your code, you can try something like:

```
Column {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### chart 3
```

It might work. More specifications about this you can find in the `flexdashboard` webpage (the same one from the print screen).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Just found out that it is not currently possible as tabs have to cover full row https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/37.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
# Your tabset title
================================
(tabset content)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm running version 1.0.143 of R-Studio, version 1.8 of rmarkdown, and 0.5.1 version of flexdashboard.  Tabs work nicely with flexdashboard.  The docs also say you can do this.

````
---
title: "Focal Chart (Top)"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
---

# Page Title

## Row {data-height=650}

### Chart One

```{r}
```

## Row {data-height=350}

### Chart 2

```{r}
```

### Chart 3 {.tabset }

#### Chart 3 Tab 1

```{r}
```

#### Chart 3 Tab 2

```{r}
```
````

Comment: Thanks, but that does not look like the configuration I am after

Comment: If it did work, my edits show where the {.tabset} directive would be place.  Of course, you answered earlier, that flexdashboard doesn't support it as is.

Comment: This seems to result in Chart 3 containing the text content:
Chart 3 Tab 1
Chart 3 Tab 2
but no tabs.