# How to have another row in my Flexdashboard if I'm using {.tabset}? R

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

Here is how my dashboard template looks. I have a {.tabset} to show two different tables for Dec 2020 & Jan 2020. But the table is not as long as the area generated and really only reaches half of it.

[image]

My desired ouutput would be something like this.

[image]

But I can't figure out how to add another level without it joining the {.tabset} or making a new column.

Here is my Rmarkdown Template

```
---
title: "Example Demo Dash"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny 
---

# Tab 1

Column 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Tab 1 Graph

# Tab 2

Column {data-width=450, .tabset} 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### December 2020 

### Janurary 2020

Column {data-width=200}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Tab 2 Col 2 Graph 1

### Tab 2 Col 2 Graph 1

### Tab 2 Col 2 Graph 3

### Tab 2 Col 2 Graph 3

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### Col 3 graph 1

### Col 3 graph 2

# tab 3
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56062827/6205282) & mentioned in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/37), creating a tab set at or below a level-3 heading is not currently supported.

To work around this, we could use `tabsetPanel()` to manually construct the tab set. Note that we will need to pass the content of the tab directly to the `tabPanel()` as an argument.

Updated R Markdown based on your example:

````
---
title: "Example Demo Dash"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny 
---

# Tab 1

Column 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Tab 1 Graph

# Tab 2

Column {data-width=450} 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Tabs

```{r}
tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel("December 2020",
           "Things about December 2020"),
  tabPanel("Janurary 2020",
           "Things about Janurary 2020")
)
```



### Col 3 Graph 1



Column {data-width=200}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Tab 2 Col 2 Graph 1

### Tab 2 Col 2 Graph 1

### Tab 2 Col 2 Graph 3

### Tab 2 Col 2 Graph 3

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### Col 3 graph 1

### Col 3 graph 2

# tab 3
````

Screenshot:
[image]